# Overflow-x overwritten by overflow-y

Tags: css, stylesheet

It seems that `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` don't behave as I expect it to behave.
If I set `overflow-x` to visible, and `overflow-y` to auto, `overflow-x` won't behave as visible, but as hidden.

Am I missing something, or is this normal?

[Here](http://cssdesk.com/z2LZD) is an example.

HTML:

```
</html
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
      <div class='content'>
        This is a content
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;

  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Use `overflow-x: scroll;` instead of `overflow-x: visible;` as mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: No, I don't want overflow-x to be scrollable, I want it to be visible.
I want a part of `content` to be out of `container`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED: After more details by OP:

The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element.

Using the overflow property with a value different than visible, its default, will create a new block formatting context. This is technically necessary as if a float would intersect with the scrolling element it would force to rewrap the content of the scrollable element around intruding floats.  The rewrap would happen after each scroll step and would be lead to a far too slow scrolling experience. Note that, by programmatically setting scrollTop to the relevant HTML element, even when overflow has the hidden value an element may need to scroll.

***Values of Overflow***:

**visible:**
Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.

**hidden**:
The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.

**scroll:**
The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment. Printers may print overflowing content.

**auto:**
Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

[**See Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow)

**Added More Details:**

from: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

> In Gecko, Safari, Opera, ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ also when combined with ‘hidden’ (in other words: ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ when combined with anything else different from ‘visible’). Gecko 1.8, Safari 3, Opera 9.5 are pretty consistent among them.

also the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x) says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well enough what I want.
I want to make a list (might be long, therefore I need scrolling), and one element of this list could be active, and have a little arrow at the left edge, at the exterior of the `container` block, therefore I need `overflow-x` to be visible.

Comment: @EtienneBrodu: Updated my answer after more details.

Comment: I know this reference, and I know exactly what each of this options does.
What I don't understand is why `visible` and `auto` can't be combined.
I am using latest firefox and chrome, and none can display a scrollbar in the y direction and visible in the x direction.

Comment: This is the browser behavior. `auto:` Depends on the user agent (desktop browser). Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

Comment: @EtienneBrodu: Added more details for your knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Actually `overflow-x` will act as `auto` in your example.

There are some combinations of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` that can't be combined, because they simply don't work. You can't have content that is scrollable inside the container in one direction, and visible outside the container in the other direction.

Comment: Could you give me some reference about this ?