# Priority/interaction between overflow and overflow-x/overflow-y

Tags: css, overflow

I want to set `overflow` (or both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`) to a certain value (`hidden`) for general objects (`*`) and override `overflow-x` (to `visible`) for particular objects (`foo`) without changing `overflow-y`.

I did:

```
*{overflow: hidden;}
foo{overflow-x: visible;}
```

When I check it in Google Chrome developer's tool, for `foo` objects, both the specifications 
`overflow: hidden` (coming from `*`) and `overflow-x: visible` (from `foo`) are effective. However, visually, it seems that `overflow: hidden` is overriding `overflow-x: visible`. This is against my expectation, which is that the more specific `foo` specification should override the less specific `*` specification.

When I instead do:

```
*{overflow: hidden;}
foo{overflow: visible;}
```

Then, it seems that `overflow: visible` (from `foo`) is overriding `overflow: hidden` (from `*`), as I intended, but then, `overflow-y` for `foo` is also set to `visible`, which I do not want.

Is it the case that `overflow` specification has priority over `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`? If not, what is going on?

---

**Edit** Maybe things are more complicated than I first thought. Setting `overflow-x` to `visible` gets rid of a horizontal scroll bar, which decreases the height of the object, and that might be interfering.

---

**Edit** Looks like there is a hint in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685039/overflow-x-overwritten-by-overflow-y). Particularly, it seems that by W3C specification, when either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is set to `visible` and the other is set to something else, the `visible` is turned into `auto`. It is a strange specification.

Comment: I don't see the issue in Chrome 30 (Mac) or Firefox 23 http://jsfiddle.net/9qHeK/ (I see the first div without scroll, and the second with horizontal scroll)

Comment: Tested with chumkiu's fiddle on Chrome 30/Firefox 25 (WinXP) and no issue.

Comment: chumkiu, Passerby Thanks for looking. Looks like it was more complicated.