# How to hide text thats overflowing horizontally but not vertically?

Tags: css

Best illustrated with a simple code example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">gggg gggg gggg gggg</div>
```

I am using properties:

```
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

and hoping that the text that goes horizontally outside of the container will be hidden, but the text/characters that span vertically will remain visible.

To clarify the use case:

I want to restrict container width and height. The overflowing text needs to be cut-off.

This can be done with simple `overflow: hidden;` and `text-wrap: word-wrap;`. The problem is that certain font characters vertically overflow outside of the line-height/container height, e.g.

[image]

Notice the "g" and "y" letters.

[image]

Therefore, my plan is no set `white-space: nowrap` and somehow force to allow only vertical overflow visibility. This causes two problems:

- It appears that I cannot have different visibility values for overflow-x/overflow-y.
- I cannot use `text-wrap` with `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: I tried something like this a while ago and i remember that if found out that you can't give overflow-x and overflow-y different values. But i might be wrong

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685039/overflow-x-overwritten-by-overflow-y

Comment: You can give them different values, but not hidden on one and visible on the other.

Comment: Feels like an XY problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code works if you increase the container height.
so say:

```
.container {
  width: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden; 
  }
```

play around with the white-space: wrap; and white-space: nowrap; to get desired result.